# Issue with XDP_REDIRECT in a namespace environment

Tags: linux, ebpf, bcc

I am trying to redirect a packet from one interface to another. I have set up three namespaces named `red`, `blue`, and `router`. `Red` and `blue` can communicate with each other only through the `router` namespace. The `router` interfaces are veth2 to `red` and veth3 to `blue`.

| **RED** |---veth0----veth2---| **ROUTER** |---veth3----veth1---| **BLUE** |

My purpose is to send pings from `red` to `blue` through `router` where my program is attached and I need to redirect because the main purpose would be to implement a NAT64 router.

The nodes currently communicate with each other, the red node can ping the blue node and vice versa, the problem is when my xdp program is attached and needs to redirect to the veth3 interface.

As xpd program, other than my implementation, I tested with BCC [examples](https://github.com/iovisor/bcc/blob/master/examples/networking) in skb mode as my NIC does not support native mode, attaching the program to veth2 and a dummy function to veth3. But it didn't work.

To solve the problem I tried using xdpdump since tcpdump doesn't capture anything. xdpdump on veth2 captures packets correctly and on output shows the packet with `XDP_REDIRECT` verdict.
On veth3 it does not receive anything.

I tried other redirect methods, such as XDP_TX and XDP_REDIRECT from veth2 to veth2 and they worked

I tried using other methods, such as `bpf_redirect()` and `map.redirect_map()` with the appropriate values but veth3 still receives nothing. Also I noticed that even when inserting non-existing ifindex I do not receive XDP_ABORTED but always XDP_REDIRECT.

Does anyone have any idea what might be causing this problem or how I could solve it?

Thank you in advance for your help.

**EDIT1:** forwarding is enabled in all namespaces.
And xdp-monitor show this:

```
    Summary                         1 redir/s               0 err,drop/s            0 xmit/s       
  kthread                       0 pkt/s                 0 drop/s                0 sched        
  redirect total                1 redir/s      
    cpu:3                       1 redir/s      
  redirect_err                  0 error/s      
  xdp_exception                 0 hit/s        
  devmap_xmit                   0 xmit/s                0 drop/s                0 drv_err/s          0.00 bulk-avg
```

**EDIT2**: this is my code, I omitted some parts for readability:

```
...
flags = BPF.XDP_FLAGS_SKB_MODE
...
b = BPF(
    text="""
#include <uapi/linux/bpf.h>
#include <linux/in.h>
#include <linux/if_ether.h>
#include <linux/ip.h>

BPF_DEVMAP(tx_port, 1);
BPF_PERCPU_ARRAY(rxcnt, long, 1);

static inline void swap_src_dst_mac(void *data)
{
    unsigned short *p = data;
    unsigned short dst[3];

    dst[0] = p[0];
    dst[1] = p[1];
    dst[2] = p[2];
    p[0] = p[3];
    p[1] = p[4];
    p[2] = p[5];
    p[3] = dst[0];
    p[4] = dst[1];
    p[5] = dst[2];
}

int xdp_redirect_map(struct xdp_md *ctx) {
    
    // omitted code, simple packet access
    
    
    struct iphdr dst_hdr = {
        .version = 4,
        .ihl = 5,
        .frag_off = bpf_htons(1<<14),
    };
    
    // blue ip address
    dst_hdr.daddr = bpf_htonl(0xc0a80301);
    
    // red ip address
    dst_hdr.saddr = bpf_htonl(0xc0a80201);
    dst_hdr.protocol = iph->protocol;
    dst_hdr.ttl = iph->ttl;
    dst_hdr.tos = iph->tos;
    dst_hdr.tot_len = iph->tot_len;

    struct iphdr *new_iph;

    new_iph = data + sizeof(*eth);
    if (new_iph + 1 > data_end)
        return XDP_DROP;

    *new_iph = dst_hdr; 
    
    struct bpf_fib_lookup fib_params = {0};
    fib_params.family = AF_INET;
    fib_params.tos = new_iph->tos;
    fib_params.l4_protocol = new_iph->protocol;
    fib_params.sport = 0;
    fib_params.dport = 0;
    fib_params.tot_len = new_iph->tot_len;
    fib_params.ipv4_src = new_iph->saddr;
    fib_params.ipv4_dst = new_iph->daddr;

    fib_params.ifindex = ctx->ingress_ifindex;

    
    rc = bpf_fib_lookup(ctx, &fib_params, sizeof(fib_params), 0);
    switch (rc)
        {
        case BPF_FIB_LKUP_RET_SUCCESS: /* lookup successful */
            memcpy(eth->h_dest, fib_params.dmac, ETH_ALEN);
            memcpy(eth->h_source, fib_params.smac, ETH_ALEN);
            int action = tx_port.redirect_map(0, 0);
            return action;
        ...
        // other cases
        ...
        }
    return XDP_PASS;
}

int xdp_dummy(struct xdp_md *ctx) {
    bpf_trace_printk("xdp_dummy\\n");
    return XDP_PASS;
}
""",
    cflags=["-w"],
)

tx_port = b.get_table("tx_port")
tx_port[0] = ct.c_int(out_idx)

in_fn = b.load_func("xdp_redirect_map", BPF.XDP)
out_fn = b.load_func("xdp_dummy", BPF.XDP)

b.attach_xdp(in_if, in_fn, flags)
b.attach_xdp(out_if, out_fn, flags)

...
```

Comment: Please share the BPF program. We can't help debug something we can't see :-)

Comment: @pchaigno Sorry for that, you are right, I added the code to the post now"

Comment: XDP is attached on ingress only so in your case it will process packets ingressing into veth2 and try to redirect them to veth3. From your description, it doesn't sound like that's what you want to achieve. My understanding was that you want packets egressing out of veth2 to go to veth3's ingress. Any reason to use XDP instead of tc?

Comment: @pchaigno My idea was to attach the program on veth2 that receives the ping in ingress from red, compute something on the packet and then use bfp_fib_lookup to redirect it to the ingress on the veth3 interface onto blue. I checked the ip packet fields and they are right. 
There is no reason behind using XDP instead of TC, I thought that XDP was more appropriate because I think I need to process the packets from another namespace on ingress only and redirect them to another interface.

Comment: Oh, right. I got confused between the ingress and egress of the veth pair :facepalm:

Comment: On tc vs. XDP, I'm mostly suggesting that because XDP on the generic hook is meant for debugging and not for real-life application. There's no performance improvement to using it vs. using tc. tc is more stable and has a lot more helpers accessible.

Comment: I don't see anything wrong in the BPF program. I'd try switching to tc first and would then try debugging with https://github.com/cilium/pwru.

Comment: @pchaigno thank you very much indeed for the advice. Anyway after that I tried with xdp-bench and it seems that the redirect was not working because of a problem between native mode and generic. Now my xdp program works! :)